# How to halt React rerendering with hooks, to freeze a certain UI part that's not in active use but expensive

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

We have quite a expensive (performance wise) grid in our React app and would love to stop rerendering async data updates while our sidebar is open or some long-running process is active.

How to stop updates for a while and stop rerendering?

Answer (score 0):

We came to use [`useMemo()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) and made a small wrapper hook called `useFreeze()` that can halt rendering easily.

```
import {useMemo} from "react";

let changing = 0;
export function useFreeze(renderer, frozen) {
    if (!frozen)
        changing = (changing + 1) % 100;
    return useMemo(renderer, [changing]);
}
```